# URL CAll Parameter Value for "Select All"

Tags: sql, url, reporting-services, call

I am accessing a third party SSRS report by using an URL Call, for the parameter value "UserID" I enter all the User IDs # I have, but every time a new user is added to the report I am having to include the new user ID manually to the URL to run. I figure it would be easier if I could use the parameter value for the "Select All" option on the report drop down menu so that it downloads everything all the time and then sort the data, but have been unable to find what the value is for that option, I have used -1,1,Null,All etc.

Q. How to figure out what is the parameter value for "Select All" or what is another way around this? I have no access to the ParameterCommand table.

Example:

/ReportServer?%2FReportList%2FReportName&BegDate=06%2F25%2F2018%2000%3A00%3A00&EndDate=06%2F25%2F2018%2023%3A59%3A00&UserID= ???

Comment: if you did that you would need something like UserID=0 or UserID=NULL and then in your SQL have a parameter and then in your SQL have a condition where null or 0 get all

Comment: Like Simon said, that option would have to be added to the report. If you can't query the available values, there's no way to automatically handle these changes.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment (and before anyone downvotes this) IF you have or can get access to the SQL \ Stored Proc you will want to do something like this

```
DECLARE @P INT = 303;
SELECT TOP 5
*
FROM
dbo.tableName
WHERE
fieldName = ISNULL(@p, fieldName)
```

This way you can pass in an ID or NULL and it will return in this case the top 5, or the individual record you want

Otherwise if you cant get to the SQL \ Stored Procedure then speak with the DBA or the DBO who should be able to help you

Comment: Thanks to Simon and Steve, I wanted to see if there was a way of doing that without having to contact the DBA, but I see probably that is what I need to do. Thank you much again.